# Searching for specific text in csv(excel format) file

Tags: python, csv, full-text-search

[CVS Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf5mF.png)

So I have a csv file(sample in link above) , with variable names in row 7  and values in row 8 . The Variable all have units after them, and the values are just numbers like this :

```
Velocity (ft/s) Volumetric (Mgal/d  Mass Flow (klb/d)   Sound Speed (ft/s)                  
.-0l.121            1.232                  1.4533434          1.233423
```

There are alot more variables, but basically I need some way to search in the csv file for the specefic unit groups, and then append the value associated with that in a list.  For example search for text "(ft/s)", and then make a dictionary with Velocity and Sound speed as Keys, and their associated values . I am unable to do this because the csv is formatted like an excel spreadsheet, and  the cells contains the whole variable name with it's unit

In the end I will have a dictionary for each unit group, and I need to do it this way because each csv file generated, the unit groups change ( ft/s becomes m/s). I also can't use excel read, because it doesn't work in IronPython.

Comment: Can you please include a sample of the raw csv file

Comment: I edited the post to include the sample

Comment: A csv file is a text based file. Can you include in the text of your question the header row and one or two rows of data.

Comment: Also in the example you have, other than the header row, the values are all numbers, and no text. The way your question read is that you have data in the csv like 1.2ft/s and you want to no how to separate the number from the unit. or am i misunderstanding your question?

Comment: This is a Microsoft excel csv file, which is opened using Excel

Comment: No I am sorry I wasn't clear enough, but I the unit ( ft/s) is grouped with the variable  so a field would have " Velocity (ft/s)  and then the value would be in the same column but the row right underneath

Comment: OK, do you have some code that works at reading the data into python yet ? If so can you post it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use csv module to read the appropriate lines into `list`s.
`defaultdict` is a good choice for data aggregation, while variable 
names and units can be easily separated by splitting on `'('`.

```
import csv
import collections 

with open(csv_file_name) as fp:
    reader = csv.feader(fp)
    for k in range(6):  # skip 6 lines
        next(reader)
    varnames = next(reader)  # 7th line
    values = next(reader)    # 8th line

groups = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for i, (col, value) in enumerate(zip(varnames, values)):
    if i < 2:
        continue
    name, units = map(str.strip, col.strip(')').split('(', 1))
    groups[units][name] = float(value)
```

**Edit:** added the code to skip first two columns

Comment: I am getting "ValueError: need more than 1 values to unpack"    for the line ur attempting to strip

Comment: You have 2 columns at the beginning which do not contain name, value pairs. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'll help with the part I think you're stuck on, which is trying to extract the units from the category. Given your data, your best bet may be to use regex, the following should work:

```
import re
f = open('data.csv')
# I assume the first row has the header you listed in your question
header = f.readline().split(',') #since you said its a csv

for item in header:
    print re.search(r'\(.+\)', item).group()
    print re.sub(r'\(.+\)', '', item)
```

That should print the following for you:

```
(ft/s)
Velocity
(Mgal/d)
Volumetric
(klb/d)
Mass Flow
(ft/s)
Sound Speed
```

You can modify the above to store these in a list, then iterate through them to find duplicates and merge the appropriate strings to dictionaries or whatnot.

Comment: If The file is a CSV, you really want to use the csv module instead of splitting on , because You could have a , in the header enclosed in quotes for example. The csv module handles all that. Otherwise a Regex was where I was trying to get to.

Comment: Good point - using the `csv` library to read in the lines is better